# what address(0) means? more specific where those token go?

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to get balanceof an address but i dont know what i should input for address token.  I looked at some other answers. One answer said the tokens send to address(0) is burn. What does that mean? Does it mean no one receive the tokens?

```
function deposit() payable {
tokens[address(0)][msg.sender] = safeAdd(tokens[address(0)][msg.sender], msg.value);
lastActiveTransaction[msg.sender] = block.number;
Deposit(address(0), msg.sender, msg.value, tokens[address(0)][msg.sender]);
}



function balanceOf(address token, address user) constant returns (uint256) {
return tokens[token][user];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`address(0)` is a short way to write [`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) (which is essentially 0x0). The address is sometimes used to burn tokens, since it's very unlikely that someone has the private key for this address.

The `deposit` function in your code assigns an amount of ETH (`msg.value`) to `tokens[0x0][sender address]`, it does not actually send any ETH or tokens.

Comment: The code is from IDEX contract. I am trying to understand the contract. So the deposit function does not do anything?

Comment: Whenever you send ETH to the contract and call the `deposit` function, it will assign that ETH to you in the `tokens` array, with `address(0)` as token address. It likely uses this address since it's not an actual token and reserved for ETH deposits.

Answer (score 2):

`address(0)` is a conceptual-abbreviation of an address with no known private key.

Naturally, it means that if you transfer your ether to this address, then no one will be able to retrieve it.

If you transfer your tokens to this address... well, that depends on how the token contract is implemented.

For example, this promiscuous contract will allow anyone to retrieve them:

```
contract ERC20Token {
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        return true;
    }

    function retrieve() public returns (bool) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += balanceOf[address(0)];
        balanceOf[address(0)] = 0;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Conventional token contracts, however, do not provide such functionality, so transferring your tokens to `address(0)` is similar to transferring your ether to this address, in the sense that no one will be able to retrieve them.

---

> One answer said the tokens send to `address(0)` is `burn`

That really depends on how you define (choose to implement) `burn`.

The ERC20 standard doesn't say anything about this, but usually, burning an amount of tokens only means that you subtract that amount from the `balanceOf` some address, and unlike `transfer`, you don't add it to the `balanceOf` of any other address.

In addition to that, the `burn` function also subtracts that amount from `totalSupply`.

But under no circumstances do you transfer those tokens to `address(0)`, since it is pointless.

If you did transfer them to `address(0)`, then it wouldn't be right to subtract that amount from `totalSupply`, and subsequently, it wouldn't be right to refer to that action as `burn`.

One point worth noting, is that when burning tokens, it is custom for the `burn` function in the token contract to emit an ERC20-standard `Transfer` event with `address(0)` as the value of the `to` parameter.

But that event is essentially symbolic, and by no means does it imply that the tokens are transferred to `address(0)`.

In short:

- When you burn tokens, the value of `totalSupply` is decreased
- When you transfer tokens to `address(0)`, the value of `balanceOf[address(0)]` is increased

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The code is from IDEX contract that i am trying to understand. So for the function deposit in the contract. There is no way to get retrieve the balance.  There is another deposit function : function depositToken(address token, uint256 amount) {
    tokens[token][msg.sender] = safeAdd(tokens[token][msg.sender], amount);
    lastActiveTransaction[msg.sender] = block.number;
    if (!Token(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, this, amount)) throw;
    Deposit(token, msg.sender, amount, tokens[token][msg.sender]);
  } What this function do ? What are differences ?